# How to get selected row index in JSF datatable?

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

I have a databale on index.xhtml

```
<h:dataTable style="border: solid 2px black;"
    value="#{IndexBean.bookList}" var="item"
    binding="#{IndexBean.datatableBooks}">

    <h:column>
        <h:commandButton value="Edit" actionListener="#{IndexBean.editBook}">
            <f:param name="index" value="#{IndexBean.datatableBooks.rowIndex}"/>
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

My bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="IndexBean")
@ViewScoped
public class IndexBean implements Serializable {
    private HtmlDataTable datatableBooks;

    public HtmlDataTable getDatatableBooks() {
        return datatableBooks;
    }

    public void setDatatableBooks(HtmlDataTable datatableBooks) {
        this.datatableBooks = datatableBooks;
    }

    public void editBook() throws IOException{
        int index = Integer.parseInt(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("index").toString());
        System.out.println(index);
    }
}
```

My problem is that I always get the same index in server log even though I click the different edit buttons. Imagine that there is one collection which is supplied to the datatable. I have not shown that in bean.

If I change scope from ViewScope to RequestScope it works fine. What can be the problem with `@ViewScoped`? Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

```
<h:column>
    <h:commandButton value="Edit" actionListener="#{IndexBean.editBook}" />
</h:column>
```

---

```
public void editBook(ActionEvent ev) throws IOException{
    if (ev.getSource() != null && ev.getSource() instanceof HtmlDataTable) {
        HtmlDataTable objHtmlDataTable = (HtmlDataTable) ev.getSource();
        System.out.println(objHtmlDataTable.getRowIndex());
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-commandlink-inside-a-datatable

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've already bound the `<h:dataTable>` component to the bean. All you need to do is:

```
public void editBook() throws IOException{
    int index = datatableBooks.getRowIndex(); // Actually not interesting info.
    Book book = (Book) datatableBooks.getRowData(); // This is what you want.
}
```

The `<f:param>` is also not needed here. For more hints also see [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html).

**Update**: I can reproduce your problem. This is likely a bug with `@ViewScoped`. When the bean is set to `@RequestScoped`, it works as expected. Also when you remove the component binding and obtain the component from the viewroot yourself, it works as expected. I've filed [issue 1658](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1658) about this.

Comment: Hi BalusC, your article is great as usual :). Your answer works if my bean is @RequestScoped. But my real question still remains that is, why is it not working in @ViewScoped? If i just change annotation from @RequestScoped to @ViewScoped, i always get the answer that i got 1st time. I need my bean to be @ViewScoped. What workaround can i possibly do?

Comment: Where do you load `bookList`?

Comment: I load it in @PostConstruct callback. Am i doing something wrong? Where should i load ?

Comment: WOW! That is an excellent article BalusC, everything that we need from a dataTable :)

Comment: @Krsna: just add a column with checkboxes/radiobuttons for multiple/single row selection.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to use the `[getRowData()][1]` method on the Java bean to directly get the object located on the line that hosts the button on which the user clicked.

An example of code:

```
public void editBook(ActionEvent evt) {
    // We get the table object
    HtmlDataTable table = getParentDatatable((UIComponent) evt.getSource());
    // We get the object on the selected line.
    Object o = table.getRowData();
    // Eventually, if you need the index of the line, simply do:
    int index = table.getRowIndex();
    // ...
}

// Method to get the HtmlDataTable.
private HtmlDataTable getParentDatatable(UIComponent compo) {
    if (compo == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (compo instanceof HtmlDataTable) {
        return (HtmlDataTable) compo;
    }
    return getParentDataTable(compo.getParent());
}
```

---

*Edit*

The JSF code now looks like:

```
<h:commandButton value="Edit" actionListener="#{IndexBean.editBook}"/>
```

In addition, do not forget to change the signature of `editBook()` method, by setting a `javax.faces.event.ActionEvent` argument.

Comment: Hello romaintaz, but i tried your solution and it doesn't seem to work. I keep getting exceptions 
"SEVERE: Received 'javax.el.MethodNotFoundException' when invoking action listener '#{IndexBean.editBook}' for component 'j_idt35'
SEVERE: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: IndexBean@d15176.editBook()"

Please help :(

Comment: Hello, Please read my edit. I did exactly what you said and i still get exception MethodNotFoundException. I did not understand what you meant by "In addition, do not modify to change the signature of editBook() method, by setting a javax.faces.event.ActionEvent argument."
I don't have anything defined in faces-config.xml. As soon as i pass ActionEvent it starts saying MethodNotFoundException

Comment: Sorry, I meant "do not *forget* to modify the method signature". Remove the `throws IOException` as it is useless. In addition, the code of your method is wrong in your edit, as the source will not be the `HtmlDatatable` itself. You will have to implement the `getParentDatatable()` method as specified to retrieve the datatable object.

Comment: Hi romaintaz, The method still doesn't work. It gives MethodNotFoundException. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use EL 2.2, for example with Tomcat7 you can try

```
<h:commandLink action="#{IndexBean.editBook(item)}" immediate="true">
```

I hope to help