# JSF DataTable - particular record

Tags: java, jsf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I pass a parameter to a commandLink inside a datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-commandlink-inside-a-datatable)

I have a MySQL database. I use only one table called USERS which has columns: userid, username, name, age. I display them by:

```
<h:dataTable 
    var="my_user"   
    value="#{user.users}"
    border="1"
    styleClass="mainTable"
    headerClass="heading"
    rowClasses="evenRow, oddRow, "
    id="rend">

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">#{lng.userId}</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{my_user.userId}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">#{lng.username}</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{my_user.username}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">#{lng.name}</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{my_user.name}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">#{lng.age}</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{my_user.age}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">#{lng.edit}</f:facet>
        <h:graphicImage name="edit.png" library="images" styleClass="tableIcon">
            <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{someClass.edit}" render="rend"/>
        </h:graphicImage>
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">#{lng.del}</f:facet>
        <h:graphicImage name="delete.png" library="images" styleClass="tableIcon">
            <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{someClass.delete}" render="rend"/>
        </h:graphicImage>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

(it is internationalized that's why are the #{lng.*})

I have 2 columns with icons for edit and delete. What should I do to get the ID of a user on particular row to pass to my functions for delete and edit?

Answer (score 0):

There are few possible ways how to do that

- In JSF 2.0 method expressions can take parameters

  ```
  <h:commandLink action="#{myBean.execute('hello')}"/>
  ```
- To use f:param tag and inside of the action method you can get that value from parameters map

  ```
  FaceContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParametersMap()
  ```
- To use f:setPropertyActionListener tag