# JSF : Passing data between 2 views

Tags: java, jsf

I'm a french computer science student, and I have a small JSF project for school. I'm a little bit noob and I try to pass data between 2 view but I fail.

First I have a view which list all my customers, in a datatable. In this datatable I have a link to show a customer profile. I use, for both view, a CustomerController which is a requestscoped managedbean.

Before I use a global sessionscoped controller but I think it's not the good way to pass data.

Then I found this article :  [JSF Best Practices](http://www.oio.de/public/java/jsf-best-practices-javaserver-faces-session-tips.htm), it recommend to use  to pass object between views. I didn't manage to make it work.

And finally I found also this question from Stackoverflow : [f:setPropertyActionListener sets null value instead of intended value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116382/fsetpropertyactionlistener-sets-null-value-instead-of-intended-value) which use

My question is : what is the best ways to pass data ? And how manage it ?

Answer (score 5):

It's explained in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters) from BalusC. You need to send id of your selected item to second view through `h:link` and catch it then with `<f:event>`.