# How to pass dynamic parameter to backing bean using EL 2.2 method expression?

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, el

I'm trying to call a function from a JSF 2.0 page in my backing bean passing a dynamic parameter. It works fine as long as im passing a static string, but when I try using a dynamic one, I always get an EL parsing error. I guess its a syntax problem, but I can't think of another way to do this using method expression. I know that I could do it with the `<f:param..../>` tag, but I'm not going to give up on this one :)

```
<h:dataTable  var="urlresult" value="#{search.searchResults_sites_urls}">
    <h:column>
        <h:form>
            <h:outputText value="#{urlresult}" />
            <h:commandLink action="#{search.showUrls(#{urlresult})}" value=" x" />
        </h:form>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

The method in the backing bean:

```
public void showUrls(String url) {
    //CODE
}
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's illegal to nest EL expressions `#{}`. Just remove the nested expression.

```
<h:commandLink action="#{search.showUrls(urlresult)}" value=" x" />
```

Also, as you're using this in a `<h:dataTable>`, in order to get it to work properly, make sure that the `#{search}` bean is in the view scope, or if it really needs to be request scoped, make sure that you're preserving the `#{search.searchResults_sites_urls}` during bean's initialization.

#### See also:

- [How can I pass selected row to commandLink inside dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-commandlink-inside-a-datatable)

Comment: haha im actually in shame right now^^ thanks alot!!!