# How to pass parameters into a p:commandbutton?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<h:outputText value="#{student.name}" />
<p:commandButton value="View" icon="ui-icon-extlink" actionListener="#{dialogView.show}" />
```

How to pass the parameter "student.name" into the DialogView class?

Comment: Or [How to pass dynamic parameter to backing bean using EL 2.2 method expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714410/how-to-pass-dynamic-parameter-to-backing-bean-using-el-2-2-method-expression)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28236228