# Sending values with <h:commandbutton> not working working properly in jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

When i tried to send some values with h:commandButton... i recieved null value in the bean...

my xhtml code is:

```
  <p:commandButton action="#{favouriteAction.setFavourite}"  value="Add as Favorite" rendered="#{favouriteBean.favouriteButton}">
  <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{favouriteAction.ngoID}" value="#{InsertDataDaoService.ngo_id}"></f:setPropertyActionListener> 
  </p:commandButton>
```

In the backing bean i just tried to print the value which i passed with my command button,but it becomes null...

In favouriteAction.java(My backing Bean)

```
  public Integer ngoID;

public Integer getNgoID() {
return ngoID;
}


public void setNgoID(Integer ngoID) {
this.ngoID = ngoID;
}

    public String setFavourite(){

      System.out.println("Ngo id: "+ngoID);
   System.out.println("Ngo id: "+getNgoID);

    return "";
}
```

In console i dint get any exceptions, my o/p is

Ngo id: 0
Ngo id: 0

that is null, and it doesnt get passed..

Comment: `favouriteBean` is request scoped? It should be at least view scoped to make this `rendered="#{favouriteBean.favouriteButton}"` work properly. There are werid problems with this.

Comment: i have no problem in rendering the command button, its properly rendered even after that bean is request scoped. my problem is with passing an value with commandbutton....

Comment: I had serveral problems with `rendered` and button commands. Button is rendered OK but problems exits on Restore View phase. On RestoreView JSF creates new request bean with `favouriteButton` set to false and it looks like button is not rendered. Werid things happens here. Probably `setPropertyActionListener` is not created at all, because it's inside not rendered component. On update model phase `favouriteButton` is true and the button is rendered properly. But it's too late: `setPropertyActionListener` was missed.

Comment: even i tried removing render option but no use.

Comment: @Peter: the action is invoked. So the `rendered` attribute isn't the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` is evaluated during the request of the form submit, not during the request of displaying the form. So if its value `#{InsertDataDaoService.ngo_id}` is not preserved for that request, then it will fail.

You have basically 2 options:

1. Ensure that `#{InsertDataDaoService.ngo_id}` is preserved for the request of the form submit. How exactly do to that depends on the functional requirements which are not clear from the question. But generally, putting the `#{InsertDataDaoService}` bean in the view scope by `@ViewScoped` and making sure that you aren't doing any business job in the getter method should be sufficient.
2. Replace `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` by `<f:param>` with `@ManagedProperty`.

   ```
   <p:commandButton action="#{favouriteAction.setFavourite}" value="Add as Favorite" rendered="#{favouriteBean.favouriteButton}">
       <f:param name="ngoID" value="#{InsertDataDaoService.ngo_id}" />
   </p:commandButton>
   ```

   with

   ```
   @ManagedProperty("#{param.ngoID}")
   private Integer ngoID;
   ```

   This way the value will be retrieved (and inlined as part of a JavaScript helper function of the `commandButton`) during the request of displaying the form, not evaluated during the request of submitting the form.

#### See also:

- [How can I pass selected row to commandLink inside dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-commandlink-inside-a-datatable)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that the value of InsertDataDaoService.ngo_id is not NULL?
Try to replace it with a constant value. Does it work?