# In-cell editing using Primefaces 3.1 datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to use in-cell editing feature of datatable using Primefaces 3.1. The example shown on their site does not show how could I use "delete" functionality. When I click on "edit" image to make changes in the table row, it works. However, nothing happens when I click on the "delete" image.

I took the code from a working demo availble at [PrimeFaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableEditing.jsf). But, this demo also does not work for "delete".

Answer (score 1):

> *However, nothing happens when I click on the "delete" image.*

It is not clear what is "when I click on the delete image". In the Primefaces showcase there is no delete image (maybe you mix it with the cross icon, but this is for discarding changes).

I think you need to add delete functionality yourself, e.g. in a separate column (example as addition to the [Primefaces showcase code](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableEditing.jsf)):

```
<p:column>
  <h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{tableBean.delete(car)}"/>
</p:column>
```

and in the backing bean:

```
public void delete(Car car) {
  carsSmall.remove(car);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I indeed mistook cross icon for delete functionality. Is there any other solution besides you suggested above to delete an entire row?

Comment: If you want to delete a single row, this is the easiest solution I know. If you want it more complicated, you could delete your row with the row index. Or bind your table to a backing bean table component ...

Comment: @user: if you want to know about all ways to get the selected table row inside your bean's action method, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-commandlink-inside-a-datatable