# ListDataModel not serializable==won´t run on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, jsf, jsf-2

Ok so I am really stuck now. I have a h:datatable and the only way to get the row details seems to be DataModel#getRowData(). Unfortunately ListDataModel which is needed to wrap the necessary data is NOT serializable so will not work on GAE, and I really need it to work! Does anyone have any idea about any workaround or some way to make it function.
Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the property `transient` (so that it will be skipped during serialization) and introduce lazy loading in the getter.

E.g.

```
private List<Item> itemList;
private transient DataModel<Item> itemModel;

public DataModel<Item> getItemModel() {
    if (itemModel == null) {
        itemModel = new ListDataModel<Item>(itemList);
    }

    return itemModel;
}
```

There are by the way alternate ways to retrieve the current row. See also [How can I pass selected row to commandLink inside dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-commandlink-inside-a-datatable)

Comment: perfectly perfect thx a lot. I just have one more question, as I used your answer and modified a bit, In fact I did not use "List<Item>" I directly did:
private transient DataModel<People> model;
public DataModel<Person> getModel() {
     if (model == null) {
         model = new ListDataModel<Person>(list of people);
     }

     return model;
 }

Regarding different ways of passing params in my case those appeared not to be working maybe due to my lack of knowladge but I would say it was because I used selectonemenu with ajax so it appears not to cooperate with options you presented.

Comment: Your concrete problem is not clear, but I think that you need to recreate the `itemModel` based on the new items inside the ajax action listener method.

Comment: well there is actually no problem I just wanted to show you that it worked without itemModel whatsoever, and just wanted to know if there are any drawbacks in that solution.

Comment: You mean, without the `itemList` property? Well there are not directly drawbacks, but if you ever need to add/remove items, then you'd need to recreate the `itemModel` everytime. With a backing `itemList` this is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats exactly what I wanted to know!