# How to passing value of hiddenFiled as parameter for actionbean?

Tags: jsf

My page display list Category Name. i want to when user clicks category name , it will
display list product by category name. in this code, i want to passing CateogryId as value of h:inputHidden. it's same as `<h:inputText value="#{produtBean.categoryId}"></h:inputText>` .

Tkanks you for reading !

**Code from xhtml**

```
<ui:repeat value="#{productBean.listCategory}" var="c">
   <h:form>
        <h:inputHidden value="#{productBean.categoryId}" ></h:inputHidden>
        <h:commandLink value="#{c.name}" action="#{productBean.listProductByCt}" ></h:commandLink>
   </h:form>
</ui:repeat>
```

**Code from ProductBean**

```
public String listProductByCt()
    {
        if(categoryId==0)
        {
            return "index";
        }
        listProduct = new ProductsDB().listProducts(categoryId);
        return "product";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<h:inputHidden>` doesn't work that way. The value you attempted to "pass" into it is also kind of weird. It's the same value for every item of the list. You should be using `<f:param>` instead. You probably also want to pass the `#{c.id}` or `#{c.name}` instead.

```
<h:commandLink value="#{c.name}" action="#{productBean.listProductByCt}">
    <f:param name="categoryId" value="#{c.id}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

With

```
@ManagedProperty("#{param.categoryId}")
private Integer categoryId; // +setter
```

Alternatively, if you're already on Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2, then you can just pass it as method argument.

```
<h:commandLink value="#{c.name}" action="#{productBean.listProductByCt(c.id)}">
```

with

```
public String listProductByCt(Integer categoryId) {
    // ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [How can I pass selected row to commandLink inside dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-commandlink-inside-a-datatable)