# which method invokes first after performing event either action or actionlistener and why?

Tags: jsf

I have a button in jsf as

after performing the event which method invokes first either method1 or method2 and WHY?

please give any suggestion if u have

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActionListeners are invoked in the order they're registered.

Action is executed after all ActionListeners.

Please check these answers for more details:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3909382/2874662
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14160010/2874662

Comment: why actionListener is only invokes first Please i want exact reason?