# Change value of bean when using p:commandButton

Tags: jsf, primefaces, javabeans, commandbutton

The value of the bean does not change when I have finisehd clicking on the button. I havent't any errors, but it does not work: the "locked" is still evaluated to false

Here is the code:

```
    <p:column>
         <p:commandButton id="downloadLink"  ajax="false"  oncomplete="#{dmFile.setLocked(true)}">
             <p:fileDownload value="#{downloadBean.downloadXMLFile(dmFile)}"  />  
        </p:commandButton> 

     <p:column headerText="lock" style="width:2%">
            <h:outputText value="#{dmFile.locked}" />              
     </p:column>
```

And my bean is

```
    public class DMFile{

          private boolean locked;

          public boolean isLocked() {
               return locked;
          }

          public void setLocked(boolean locked) {
              this.locked = locked;
           }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [reference guide](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/4.0/primefaces-p/commandButton.html), the attribute `oncomplete` does:

- ***Client side** callback to execute when ajax request is completed.*

You can't reference to a bean action! It's used, for example, to call a `JavaScript` method and executed by the client.

Full reference can be found [HERE](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/4.0/primefaces-p/commandButton.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can use f:setPropertyActionListener

```
<p:commandButton id="downloadLink"  ajax="false" >
             <f:setPropertyActionListener value="true" target="#{dmFile.locked}" />
             <p:fileDownload value="#{downloadBean.downloadXMLFile(dmFile)}"  />  
</p:commandButton>
```

Let me know if it has worked for anybody.

Comment: It won't run **after** the commandButton action... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159967/is-it-possible-to-call-setpropertyactionlistener-before-actionlistener