# <f:setPropertyActionListener> Parent is not of type ActionSource

Tags: jsf, parent, setpropertyactionlistener

I would like to pass value when I click on a table row:

```
<h:outputLink id="lnkHidden" value="DatacenterProfile.html" style="text-decoration:none; color:white;">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{DatacentersController.selectedId}" value="#{item.componentStatsId}" />
</h:outputLink>
```

I get this error:

> <f:setPropertyActionListener> Parent is not of type ActionSource, type is: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputLink@aa25b91

Is there any appropriate JSF tag which can be used to replace `<h:outputLink>`?

Comment: @BalusC If correct I need to make POST request.

Comment: What JSF tag would you recommend?

Comment: This answers your http://xyproblem.info: [How can I pass selected row to commandLink inside dataTable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4994458)

Answer (score 5):

The `f:setPropertyActionLister` only works for [`ActionSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/ActionSource.html) components like `h:commandLink` and `h:commandButton`. You should use one of these if you want to do it that way. See also

Comment: Any suggestions which one I can use?

Comment: This depends on whether you want to render a link or a button? :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want your URL (href) to be conserved, or do you just want it to act like a button ?

1. If you want the URL to be conserved (with, obviously its params, so you can open it in other tabs etc...), just use `f:param` instead of `f:setPropertyActionLister`.
2. If losing URL display (no meaningful url is displayed), you can use as Chkal said, `commandButton` or `commndLink`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @BalusC answer. I have used something like this in my project.

```
<h:commandButton 
       id="" 
       styleClass="" 
       type="submit" 
       rendered="#{}" 
       value="#{}" 
       action="#{}"> 
       <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{}" value="#{}" /> 
</h:commandButton>
```

You can pass/use attributes based on your scenarios.