# How can i send value with commandLInk

Tags: jsf, parameters, datatable, commandlink

I have a controller named `clController`. This controller has `code` property and I want to send this `code` property a value.

```html
<h:form>
    <h:inputHidden value="#{item.code}" />
    <h:commandLink action="#{clController.getByCode()}" value="#{item.code}" />
</h:form>
```

above code is in a datatable. How can i send item.code value to this property?

Comment: Wait wait, you have the `<h:form/>` *inside* the datatable?

Comment: fyi, value is the text displayed within the <a> tag link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass a parameter to a commandLink inside a datatable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-commandlink-inside-a-datatable)

Comment: Another duplicate of his own question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244590/jsf-sending-a-hidden-input-to-another-jsf

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{clController.code}" value="#{item.code}">
```

if you use JSF 2.0, or simply change the signature of your action method to `getByCode(YourClass code)` and pass the value as a parameter

```
<h:commandLink action="#{clController.getByCode(item.code)}" value="#{item.code}" />
```

Comment: Stop using `<code>` tags and read message formatting rules behind the `[?]` icon in the message editor :)