# JSF sending a hidden input to another jsf

Tags: java, jsf

I have below code:

```html
<h:commandLink action="#{clController.action()}" 
    value="#{item.code}" >
    <input type="hidden" name="address" value="#{item.address}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="address" value="#{item.name}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="address" value="#{item.taxDept}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Page lists more than 12 links like above. What i want to do sending all these hiddens to another jsf whichever user clicks.

When I click commandLink it goes other page. But How can I show these values?

Comment: Is the answer more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't use `<input />` directly in JSF.
2. Your inputs have all the same name.
3. In JSF, values posted are the one inside the same `<h:form />` as the action (if not specified).

You can use something simple as a parameter :

```
<h:commandLink action="start" actionListener="#{clController.actionListener}">
    <f:attribute name="item" value="#{item}" />
</h:commandLink>

public void actionListener(ActionEvent event)
{
    ClDataModel item = (ClDataModel)event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("item");

    System.out.print(item.getTaxDept());
    System.out.print(item.getAddress());
    System.out.print(item.getName());
}
```

Comment: None of the 3 points mentioned are fully correct and the first two are basically wrong. The answer is nonetheless correct, though there are many more ways to achieve that goal.

Comment: Read his other question that is a duplicate but have more informations : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245343/why-jsf-sends-the-first-links-information-to-the-back-bean