# How to restore a managedBean from another managedBean

Tags: jsf, view-scope

I have two pages(let's say page1 and page2), and one magaedBean for each page (mb1 and mb2).
in the mb1, i have an instance of the mb2, with all their attributes previously setted by a method in mb1. Something like this:

```
public Mb1(){}//Default constructor
private Mb2 mb2;//Instance of Mb2 inside Mb1
```

what i want is, from a method in mb1, to open the view page2 in a way that the controller of page2(mb2) is the instance stored in the mb1.

Both my managedBeans MUST be ViewScoped, i know i can do it by use session scoped but this is not what i need.
Is tere a way to do this?

Comment: which version of JSF are you using? I wouldn't make a bean responsible of initializing another one...

Comment: Also, what does Mb1 do that can't Mb2 do by itself?

Comment: it's a communication between the pages... this are two crud pages, each one for a specific entity

Comment: Why can't you then pass the id (edit) or none at all (create) to the second page instead of a fully created an initialized bean? Also, please, which version of JSF are you using?

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-commandlink-inside-a-datatable/4994833#4994833

Answer (score 0):

Why is a managed bean responsible of initializing another one? I'd rather provide the necessary information to `Mb2` so he can initialize himself.

If you're set on passing an object and avoiding `Mb2`'s self initialization (and assuming you're using JSF 2), I suggest you take a look at JSF's *Flash Scope*.

Tough *Flash* is not a scope per se, it's a feature based (AFAIK) on Ruby's implementation of the POST - REDIRECT - GET pattern. Instead of having a bean as a parameter, you can create your own object that stores the data and have `Mb2` operate on it.

When you need to navigate to `page2`, just store that item in the flash and retrieve it later, when Mb2 is created.

To store it you need the `Flash`, which can be obtained in multiple ways:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash();
```

Or

```
@ManagedProperty("#{flash}")
private Flash flash;

public void setFlash(Flash jsfFlash) {
    flash = jsfFlash;
}
```

*Flash* itself is a map (just like the ones for a request and the session), so you can put your object there:

```
ManagingObject o = new ManagingObject();
//Initialize the object and set the desired properties.
flash.put("ManagingObject", mo);
```

You can, then, get that object in `Mb2` by obtaining the `Flash` and then taking the object from it, for example, in a `preRenderView` defined event.