# Passing parameters between managed beans

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, javabeans

I am trying to pass some parameters from one managed bean to another. I saw similar question and applied their solutions but does not work. Here is the code:

In my moneytransfer.xhtml file:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{moneyTransferBean.transferAccounts()}" value="Continue">
   <f:param name="sender" value="#{extTableSelectionBean.sender}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

My extTableSelectionBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ExtTableSelectionBean implements Serializable {
    private Account sender;

    public void setSender(Account sender){
        this.sender=sender;
    }


    public Account getSender(){
        return sender;
    }
```

and the moneyTransferBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MoneyTransferBean {
     @ManagedProperty("#{extTableSelectionBean .sender}")
     private Account sender;
     //NO SETTER-GETTER FOR sender here

     public void transferAccounts() throws IOException {        

         if (sender != null)
         {  
             FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("transferaccount.xhtml");
         }
     }
}
```

I see that in extTableSelectionBean, the "sender" is succesfully set. The problem is, when i get to the moneyTransferBean, sender becomes null. What should i do about it, what am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things are mixed here. Injecting a bean into another bean and adding a parameter to `commandButton`.

`Account sender` is tried to inject to  `MoneyTransferBean`, however there is no action will be performed since there is no getter setter, so injection will be failed.

`sender` is tried to set through a commandButton to send as parameter, but there is no implementation for it. @ManagedProperty annotation should be changed for reading the parameter from command button. I assume that sender is set in any place before submitting of `commandButton`

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.sender}")
private Account sender;
```

There are further methods to send or set data in managed beans. Please read the BalusC answer.

**Related Post**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4994833/892994