# f:setPropertyActionListener always setting null

Tags: jsf, facelets

I'm trying to put the currently iterated `<p:dataTable var>` as a property of a managed bean using `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`. However, it is always set as `null`.

The view, `dentistas.xhtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"  
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">  

<h:head>  

</h:head>  
<h:body>  
    <ui:composition template="/templates/template.xhtml">  

        <ui:define name="content">  
            <h:form id="formDentistas">  

                <p:growl autoUpdate="true" />  

                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-plus" value="Cadastrar"  
                    id="cadastrar" oncomplete="dialogCadastrar.show()" />  


                <p:dataTable var="dentista" value="#{dentistaMB.dentistas}"  
                    paginator="true" emptyMessage="Não foi encontrado nenhum registro"  
                    rows="10" id="dataTableDentistas">  

                    <f:facet name="header">Lista de Dentistas</f:facet>  
                    <p:column headerText="Nome" sortBy="nome" filterBy="nome" id="nome"  
                        width="200px">  
                    #{dentista.pessoaFisica.nome}  
                </p:column>  

                    <p:column headerText="Data Nascimento" sortBy="dataNascimento"  
                        filterBy="dataNascimento" id="dataNascimento" width="60px">  
                    #{dentista.pessoaFisica.dataNascimento}  
                </p:column>  

                    <p:column headerText="CRO" sortBy="cro" filterBy="cro" id="cro"  
                        width="60px">  
                    #{dentista.cro}  
                </p:column>  

                    <p:column headerText="Ações" style="width:50px;">  
                        <p:commandButton value="Alterar" icon="ui-icon-pencil">  
                           <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{dentistaMB.selectedDentista}" value="#{dentista}" />                                  
                        </p:commandButton>  

                        <p:commandButton value="Remover" icon="ui-icon-trash"  
                            actionListener="#{dentistaMB.deletar}">  
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{dentistaMB.selectedDentista}" value="#{dentista}" />  
                        </p:commandButton>  
                    </p:column>  

                </p:dataTable>  
            </h:form>  

            <ui:include src="/tabelas/dialog_insert_dentista.xhtml" />  


        </ui:define>  
    </ui:composition>  


</h:body>  
</html>
```

The managed bean, `DentistaMBImpl`:

```
package br.com.odontonew.mb;  

import java.util.List;  
import java.util.Map;  

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;  
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;  
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;  
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;  
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;  
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;  
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;  
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;  
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;  
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;  

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;  
import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;  

import br.com.odontonew.bean.Dentista;  
import br.com.odontonew.bean.EstadoCivil;  
import br.com.odontonew.bean.PessoaFisica;  
import br.com.odontonew.bean.Sexo;  
import br.com.odontonew.bean.SituacaoPessoa;  
import br.com.odontonew.bean.Uf;  
import br.com.odontonew.bo.BasicBO;  
import br.com.odontonew.exception.BOException;  

@ManagedBean(name = "dentistaMB")  
@ViewScoped  
public class DentistaMBImpl extends BasicMBImpl {  

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DentistaMBImpl.class);  

    @ManagedProperty("#{dentistaBO}")  
    private BasicBO dentistaBO;  
    private Dentista dentista;  
    private Dentista selectedDentista;  
    private List<Dentista> dentistas;  

    // Lists  
    private List<EstadoCivil> estadosCivis;  
    private List<SituacaoPessoa> situacoesPessoa;  
    private List<Sexo> sexos;  
    private List<Uf> ufs;  

    @PostConstruct  
    public void init() {  
        dentista = new Dentista();  
        dentista.setPessoaFisica(new PessoaFisica());  
        dentista.getPessoaFisica().setSexo(new Sexo());  
        dentista.getPessoaFisica().setEstadoCivil(new EstadoCivil());  
        dentista.getPessoaFisica().setSituacao(new SituacaoPessoa());  
        dentista.getPessoaFisica().setUf(new Uf());  
        estadosCivis = (List<EstadoCivil>) dentistaBO  
                .findByNamedQuery(EstadoCivil.FIND_ALL);  
        situacoesPessoa = (List<SituacaoPessoa>) dentistaBO  
                .findByNamedQuery(SituacaoPessoa.FIND_ALL);  
        sexos = (List<Sexo>) dentistaBO.findByNamedQuery(Sexo.FIND_ALL);  
        ufs = (List<Uf>) dentistaBO.findByNamedQuery(Uf.FIND_ALL);  
    }  

    public void salvar(ActionEvent event) {  
        try {  
            dentista = (Dentista) dentistaBO.save(dentista);  
            addInfoMessage("Dentista salvo com sucesso");  
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute(  
                    "dialogCadastrar.hide()");  

        } catch (BOException e) {  
            addErrorMessage(e.getMessage());  
        }  
    }  

    public void atualizar(ActionEvent event) {  
        try {  
            dentistaBO.update(selectedDentista);  
            addInfoMessage("Dentista atualizado com sucesso");  
        } catch (BOException e) {  
            addErrorMessage(e.getMessage());  
        }  
    }  

    public void deletar(ActionEvent event) {  
        try {             
            dentistaBO.delete(selectedDentista);  
            addInfoMessage("Dentista deletado com sucesso");  
        } catch (BOException e) {  
            addErrorMessage(e.getMessage());  
        }  
    }  

    public List<Dentista> getDentistas() {  
        try {  
            if (dentistas == null)  
                dentistas = (List<Dentista>) dentistaBO  
                        .findByNamedQuery(Dentista.FIND_ALL_COMPLETO);  

            return dentistas;  
        } catch (BOException e) {  
            addErrorMessage(e.getMessage());  
            return null;  
        }  
    }  

    /* gets and sets */  

    public Dentista getSelectedDentista() {  
        return selectedDentista;  
    }  

    public void setSelectedDentista(Dentista selectedDentista) {  
        this.selectedDentista = selectedDentista;  
    }  

    public Dentista getDentista() {  
        return dentista;  
    }  

    public void setDentista(Dentista dentista) {  
        this.dentista = dentista;  
    }  

    public Logger getLogger() {  
        return logger;  
    }  

    public void setLogger(Logger logger) {  
        this.logger = logger;  
    }  

    public List<EstadoCivil> getEstadosCivis() {  
        return estadosCivis;  
    }  

    public void setEstadosCivis(List<EstadoCivil> estadosCivis) {  
        this.estadosCivis = estadosCivis;  
    }  

    public List<SituacaoPessoa> getSituacoesPessoa() {  
        return situacoesPessoa;  
    }  

    public void setSituacoesPessoa(List<SituacaoPessoa> situacoesPessoa) {  
        this.situacoesPessoa = situacoesPessoa;  
    }  

    public List<Sexo> getSexos() {  
        return sexos;  
    }  

    public void setSexos(List<Sexo> sexos) {  
        this.sexos = sexos;  
    }  

    public void setDentistas(List<Dentista> dentistas) {  
        this.dentistas = dentistas;  
    }  

    public List<Uf> getUfs() {  
        return ufs;  
    }  

    public void setUfs(List<Uf> ufs) {  
        this.ufs = ufs;  
    }  

    public BasicBO getDentistaBO() {  
        return dentistaBO;  
    }  

    public void setDentistaBO(BasicBO dentistaBO) {  
        this.dentistaBO = dentistaBO;  
    }  



}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here,

```
<p:commandButton value="Remover" icon="ui-icon-trash"  
    actionListener="#{dentistaMB.deletar}">  
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{dentistaMB.selectedDentista}" value="#{dentista}" />  
</p:commandButton>
```

you're performing the delete in an `actionListener` method instead of an `action` method. This is not right. Business actions should be performed in the `action` method. All action listeners, including the `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`, are invoked *before* `action` method in the very same order as they are declared and assigned on the command component. So, in effects, the delete is first invoked and then the property is set. That explains why the property is `null` during the delete.

The fix is simple: make it a real `action` method:

```
<p:commandButton value="Remover" icon="ui-icon-trash"  
    action="#{dentistaMB.deletar}">  
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{dentistaMB.selectedDentista}" value="#{dentista}" />  
</p:commandButton>
```

Don't forget to remove the `ActionEvent` argument:

```
public void deletar() {  
    // ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, if you happen to target a Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 compatible container, then you can even get rid of that `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` altogether:

```
<p:commandButton value="Remover" icon="ui-icon-trash"  
    action="#{dentistaMB.deletar(dentista)}" />
```

With:

```
public void deletar(Dentista selectedDentista) {  
    // ...
}
```

See also point 3 of [How can I pass selected row to commandLink inside dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-commandlink-inside-a-datatable/4994833#4994833)

Comment: This is the best ever ever ever answer why the hack that propertyactionlistener is null !! Seriuosly ,you should get Noble prize for having such deepest JSF knowledge.