# ActionListener not working properly with ViewScope?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

It's me again,

I've got this trouble since switch using `action` to `actionListener`. This is a strange trouble and I don't know why it happened.

When I tried to delete an item from PrimeFaces data table, *I will get NullPointerException. But, if I edit that item first then come back to delete*, it will be fine!?

I'm using actionListener to use Ajax in JSF. When I used action, it still worked properly.

**JSF Page**

```
<p:commandButton id="editButton" icon="ui-icon-pencil"
                 value="#{appBundle.Edit}"
                 action="detail.xhtml?faces-redirect=true">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{a}"
                                 target="#{academicManagedBean.academicSelected}"/>
</p:commandButton>
<p:commandButton id="deleteButton" icon="ui-icon-trash"
                 value="#{appBundle.Delete}"
                 actionListener="#{academicManagedBean.delete}"
                 update=":growl,datalist">
    <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{a}"
                                 target="#{academicManagedBean.academicSelected}" />
</p:commandButton>
<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">  
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button"
                     styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"/>  
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button"
                     styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>       
</p:confirmDialog>
```

**Managed Bean Class**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class AcademicManagedBean extends TblAcademic implements Serializable {

    private List<TblAcademic> all;
    private static TblAcademic academicSelected;

    public AcademicManagedBean() {
        super();
    }

    public List<TblAcademic> getAll() {
        try {
            all = new com.rdb.bll.AcademicBLL().getAll();
            return all;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AcademicManagedBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void add(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {
        boolean check = new com.rdb.bll.AcademicBLL().add(this);
        if (check) {
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage("Congratulation, new student has been added successfully!");
        } else {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.rdb.service.AppBundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        }
    }

    public void update(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {
        boolean check = new com.rdb.bll.AcademicBLL().update(AcademicManagedBean.academicSelected);
        if (check) {
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage("Congratulation, student has been updated successfully!");
        } else {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.rdb.service.AppBundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        }
    }

    public void delete(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {
        boolean check = new com.rdb.bll.AcademicBLL().delete(AcademicManagedBean.academicSelected);
        if (check) {
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage("Congratulation, student has been deleted successfully!");
        } else {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.rdb.service.AppBundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        }
    }

    public String studentDetail() {
        TblStudent std = new com.rdb.bll.StudentBLL().getById(AcademicManagedBean.academicSelected.getStudentRollNo());
        new StudentManagedBean().setStudentSelected(std);

        return "/backend/student/detail.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public String getClassNameById(int classId) {
        TblClass objClass = new com.rdb.bll.ClassBLL().getById(classId);
        return objClass.getClassName();
    }

    public TblAcademic getAcademicSelected() {
        return academicSelected;
    }

    public void setAcademicSelected(TblAcademic academicSelected) {
        AcademicManagedBean.academicSelected = academicSelected;
    }
```

Did I do anything wrong? Please help me to make it correct, thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<p:commandButton id="deleteButton" icon="ui-icon-trash"
                 value="#{appBundle.Delete}"
                 actionListener="#{academicManagedBean.delete}"
                 update=":growl,datalist">
    <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{a}"
                                 target="#{academicManagedBean.academicSelected}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

you're performing the delete in an `actionListener` method instead of an action method. This is not right. Business actions should be performed in the `action` method. All action `listeners`, including the `<f:setPropertyActionListener>,` are invoked before `action` method in the very same order as they are declared and assigned on the command component. So, in effects, the delete is first invoked and then the property is set. That explains why the property is null during the delete.

The fix is simple: make it a real action method:

```
<p:commandButton id="deleteButton" icon="ui-icon-trash"
                 value="#{appBundle.Delete}"
                 action="#{academicManagedBean.delete}"
                 update=":growl,datalist">
    <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{a}"
                                 target="#{academicManagedBean.academicSelected}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Don't forget to remove the ActionEvent argument:

```
public void delete() {  
    // ...
}
```

This is extracted from Answer posted by JSF Guru Balcus here [Posted by JSF Guru](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358467/fsetpropertyactionlistener-always-setting-null/18358702#comment31860761_18358702)

Comment: I don't understand. Inside the detail page or add new page, I'm using `actionListener` too and it's still working fine. Anyway, your solution solved my problem. Thanks you.