# af:setPropertyListener not working, invoking (nor f:setPropertyActionListener)

Tags: java, jsf-2, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Having a basic JSF project with ADF which needs to delete a row from a table (every row is an `Album`) with a Delete button which is next to the requested row (each row has one). 
 Using JDeveloper trying with ADF (tried this solution too with just simple JSF:([How can I pass selected row to commandLink inside dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-commandlink-inside-a-datatable))
However, it seems to me that `setPropertyListener` and `setPropertyActionListener` are not invoking (put some dummy comments in the `setCommon()` function, not seen, also the beautiful comment from `del_action()` not showing). Also tried with `@SessionScoped` bean.
 Main question: what went wrong that even the value passing is not working? 
Any ideas would be highly appreciated (and sorry for the lack of syntax highlight, still a newbie, have not figured it out yet) :)

The JSF part:

```
<af:column sortable="false" headerText=" " align="start" id="c4"> 
 <h:commandButton value="Delete" id="del" action="#{backing_main.del_action}">
  <af:setPropertyListener to="#{backing_main.common}" from="#{row.albumName}" type="action" />
 </h:commandButton>
</af:column>
```

Backing Bean:

```
   @ManagedBean(name="backing_main")
   @ViewScoped

   ...

    private String common; 
    public void setCommon(String common){
        System.out.print("!!!SET!!!!!");
        this.common = common;
    }

    public String getCommon(){
        return this.common;
    }

    public void del_action() {
        System.out.print("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Delete1");     
    }

    public static class Album{

            String artist;
            String albumName;
            //constructor, setter, all the expected stuff
    }
```

Comment: The function del_action() need to return a string!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better use ADF components to get expected result: `af:commandButton`, instead `h:commmandButton`.

And if you ain't using taskflow to delete row, then you better switch to `actionListener`, instead of `action`.

Comment: Later I utterly rewrote my program, and I was using the ADF components, that is why I accepted your answer. :)