# How to Pass parameter between managedBean

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, managed-bean

I have this scenario:

1. page1.xhtml managed by loginBean.java
2. page2.xhtml managed by dettaglioBean.java

I've got a `goToDetail(String item)` method in `loginBean` that should lead to page2.xhtml when item is selected.

When I try to pass properties from `loginBean` to `dettaglioBean`, properties are `null` in `dettaglioBean` when page2.xhtml is rendered or `@PostConstruct` is raised.

Here is the `goToDetail` method:

```
public String goToDetail(VStatoavanzamentoriep item) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        DettaglioBean bean = (DettaglioBean)     context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{dettaglioBean}",     DettaglioBean.class);

    bean.setItem(item);

    return Constants.PageID.DettaglioID;
}
```

and `dettaglioBean` is declared as `managedBean` in faces-config.xml

When I go to page2.xhtml, `item` is `null`.

Should I use dependency injection including:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{dettaglioBean}") //+ setter
private DettaglioBean dettaglioBean;
```

in `loginBean`?

Comment: What are the scope of the two beans ?

Comment: They are both SessionScooped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the values in loginBean by injecting the loginBean into dettaglioBean and not the other way round, since it is the values in loginBean that you need in dettaglioBean.

```
 @ManagedProperty("#{loginBean}") 
 private LoginBean loginBean;
```

When the JSF implementation comes across the EL, it searches for the bean object in the various scope maps and when it finds it, injects it into your dettaglioBean.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Could you explain me why the code 
    bean.setItem(item);
is not executed in my first version?

Comment: It should work. I just tried it and it works for me. Does the above code work for you ?

Comment: Yes it works. I have found why my first code didn't work: 'item' in DettaglioBean was declared as private!

Comment: item should be private. only the getter and setter methods should be public.

Comment: Would be more helpful if you could provide the relevant code from both jsf pages and the beans

Answer (score 0):

There are  methods to send or set data in managed beans. Please read the BalusC answer.

Related Post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4994833/892994

Comment: I don't think to have the same problem. I have to pass data between managedBeans: from bean loginBean, when goToDetail method is raised, I need to programmatically access to dettaglioBean, set some properties and switch to page2.xhtml which is managed by dettaglioBean. 

I already pass 'item' from page1.xhtml to loginBean via

    <p:commandLink id="buttonCodRichiesta" action="#{loginBean.vaiDettaglio(item)}" ajax="false">