# Store value into managed bean with <ace:ajax>

Tags: ajax, jsf, icefaces

I am having trouble storing a value in my bean when a command link is pressed.
I am trying to set up an ajax request so that when I click the link, the value of `car.carrierId` is stored in the `partyRoleId` field of my managed bean `generalCarrierData`. This is very simple, but I am not sure what needs to be done to enable this to work.

The relevant part of my .xhtml file is as follows, the ajax requets in question is at the bottom, however, I have added the top part of my  for context:

```
    <h:form>

<h:outputText id="partyRoleId" value="#{generalCarrierBean.partyRoleId}"/>

        <ace:dataTable id="carriersTable" scrollable="true"
            emptyMessage="No records Available." paginator="true"
            scrollHeight="600" paginatorAlwaysVisible="true"
            paginatorPosition="bottom"
            paginatorTemplate="  {CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown} Total Items: #{generalCarrierBean.rowCount}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="all,100,300,500,700, 1000"
            rows="#{generalCarrierBean.rowsDisplayed}"
            value="#{generalCarrierBean.allCarriers}" var="car"
            columnOrdering="#{generalCarrierBean.columnOrder}"
            headerColumnOrdering="#{generalCarrierBean.columnHeaderOrder}">
            <ace:ajax event="rowsPerPage" render="@form" execute="@this" />
            <ace:tableConfigPanel id="tableConfig"
                dragHandle=".ui-tableconf-header" columnNameConfigurable="true"
                columnVisibilityConfigurable="true"
                columnOrderingConfigurable="true" columnSortingConfigurable="true"
                modal="true" type="last-col">
            </ace:tableConfigPanel>

            <ace:column id="name" filterValue="#{generalCarrierBean.nameColumn}"
                headerText="#{generalCarrierBean.columns[1].name}"
                rendered="#{generalCarrierBean.columns[1].rendered}"
                sortBy="#{car.name}" filterBy="#{car.name}"
                filterMatchMode="contains"
                sortPriority="#{generalCarrierBean.columns[1].sortPriority}"
                sortAscending="#{generalCarrierBean.columns[1].sortAscending}">

                <h:commandLink id="getId" rendered="#{not empty car.name}"
                    value="#{car.name}">
                    <f:ajax event="click"  execute="#[car.carrierId]}" render="#{generalCarrierBean.partyRoleId}" > </f:ajax>
                </h:commandLink>

            </ace:column>
```

In my managed bean `generalCarrierBean` I have the following field with getters and setters:

```
-private String partyRoleId = "";
```

Comment: I have found the answer to what I wanted here:

http://stackoverflow.com/q/4994458/3388138