# Init method is not filled in even with parameters

Tags: jsf, jboss, seam

I have lost a few hours trying to figure out why I can not retrieve the parameters of my link. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-commandlink-inside-a-datatable) question, I did my link with passing parameters. My problem is relatively easy, if I can get the parameters in the popup that opens when the user clicks the link. Except that I can not get them.

My class has a method annotated with [@Create](https://docs.jboss.org/seam/1.1GA/api/org/jboss/seam/annotations/Create.html) that every time the object is initialized it executes this method.

The only way I can get the `idsess_` parameter is in the URL, but I can not pass any parameters I want the URL.

In short, by clicking on my `<a:commandLink>` wish the `<f:param>`'s were passed to the bean in a matter and the same to process according to these parameters.

*Edit: changed my code and created my own action. In this case I was reusing an action of another view. I recreated my action and used the method described in the answer that was accepted*

Comment: Bring your code here

Comment: When I put an `action` on `<a:commandLink>` e.g. `<a:commandLink action="#{bean.test()}">` the method `init()` comes filled, but the popup already rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your `<a:commandLink/>` component is? (Im assumed you re-mapped `a4j:commandLink` somehow?)

I think the problem you are having is that the `@RequestParameter` variables are only populated when the page first renders, when you click the commandLink you are performing a postback so the values are lost.

You should try doing a redirect instead (ie. using `<s:link>` with `<f:param>` rather than commandLink) or you can pass the parameters using pages.xml to bind the request params, using this markup:

```
<page view-id="/your-page.xhtml">
        <param name="pId" value="#{bean.variable}" required="false" />
        <action execute="#{bean.action}" />
</page>
```