# Primefaces binding datatable with viewscope

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, binding, datatable

I'm currently building an xhtml page based on Primefaces 3.5 (which I can't update...not lucky this time!).

In this page I need to build dynamically different datatables so I thought that unique way to achieve my task is through the binding method.

So I've made:

```
<p:dataTable id="bindQTable" var="item"
        value="#{bindingHtmlTableClass.items}"
        binding="#{bindingHtmlTableClass.dataTable}">

        <p:column headerText="Name Column">
            <h:outputText value="#{item}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:commandButton value="remove"
                action="#{bindingHtmlTableClass.remove}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

and the bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="bindingHtmlTableClass")
@RequestScoped
public class BindingHtmlTableClass implements Serializable{ 
    private List<String> items;  
    private DataTable dataTable;  

    @PostConstruct
    private void buildUp(){ 
        System.out.println("postconstruct!");
        items  = new ArrayList<String>();

        items.add("X");
        items.add("Y");
    }

     ...getters,setters... 
}
```

The problem now is that I would need to update the tables and especially after a poll period I need to update the values within them.

But i'm in a Request Scope and I can't use a View Scope because of binding.
Is there a better way to implement such thing?

EDIT 4 BalusC: why i need binding the datatable? Because i need to show a datatable linked to a serie of different connection to different installation of RabbitMQ, which is not a known number. My boss asked me to put each RabbitMQ server in a different DataTable where each queue is represented in a different row. Each column needs to show actual queue size plus a button or more to manage the queue (purging, deleting...).

Thanks!

Comment: This question is only answerable if you tell why exactly you thought that you need to bind a component to the bean, so that the right way for that can be answered without using binding. After that, changing the bean scope shouldn't be a problem anymore. My educated guess says that this answers your actual problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4994458 Regardless, this is food for read: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14911158

Comment: As per your edit, I wasn't really asking for the business reason, but for the technical reason. For example, is it because you need to be able to do a `dataTable.setSomething(something)` or so? If so, the answer would be to just use `<p:dataTable something="#{bean.something}">` instead.

Comment: Oh i see. I didn't put an actual instance of datatable and use a set method to fill it. No my need is to put different datatables (don't know how many...imagine a loop of n times with object value that has row values in it...) and be able to refresh their status like in a viewscope. Am I clear now?

Comment: No, it's still not clear. Nonetheless, there's **nothing** which can only be achieved by fiddling with components in Java and not using declarative XHTML. So it's definitely possible to get rid of the binding on bean property altogether.

Comment: Well...i'm the worst explainer of the Universe. Well..let's say you have to show an "x" number of datatables in a viewscope xhtml. What do u do?

Comment: Just `<ui:repeat value="#{bean.tables}" var="table"><p:dataTable value="#{table.items}" var="item">` with a `private List<List<Item>>`? See also that food link http://stackoverflow.com/q/14911158 Ctrl+F on "dynamic model".

Comment: Ok, that does sounds interesting and seems to fit my needs. Let me dig in articles and examples. thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94021/discussion-between-mark-and-balusc).