# p:fileDownload reloads page without query string when an exception is thrown

Tags: jsf, primefaces, download

i have problem with `<p:fileDownload>` when i try to download file and bean throws exception page reloaded and removes parametr from url:

```
 <p:commandLink update=":gform:growl" ajax="false"
                                   onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(null, stop)">
                        <i class="fa fa-paperclip fa-2x sc-badge-icon sc-border-right hover"></i>
                        <p:fileDownload value="#{taskFileController.getFile(cc.attrs.scFile)}"/>
                    </p:commandLink>
```

bean code:

```
public void getFile(ScFile scFile) throws IOException {
    try {
        File file = ftpController.downLoadFile(scFile);
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + scFile.getFileName() + "\"");
        response.setContentLength((int) file.length());

        input = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        out = response.getOutputStream();
        while (input.read(buffer) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer);
            out.flush();
        }
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getResponseComplete();
    } catch (GrowlException e) {
        GrowlException.show(e);
    } catch (Throwable err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
        GrowlException.show("Возникла ошибка при скачивании файла");
    }
}
```

P.s. when no exception page do not reloaded.
P.s.s. bean is `@Named` and `@Stateless`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated on the [Primefaces showcases](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml) your `getFile()` method must return a `StreamedContent` instead of writing to the response output and the return value may not be `null`:

```
public StreamedContent getFile(ScFile scFile) throws IOException {
    File file = ftpController.downLoadFile(scFile);
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
    String filename = scFile.getFileName();
    String contentType = "attachment;filename=\"" + scFile.getFileName() + "\"";
    StreamedContent file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, contentType, filename);

    return file;
}
```

Preventing it from being `null` due to whatever cause can be solved in a good or dirty way:

1. (dirty) Simply provide an empty DefaultStreamdContent: 
   `new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[] {});`
2. Create a two stage download process. First you use an ajax button which the user presses in order to determine if the file is available. The user then receives a second link (the pf download button) in order to download the content you have already prepared in your bean.

Comment: does not matter, page reloaded when StreamedContent returns null (on exception)

Comment: @GeorgeVassilev The page will allways reload if an error is thrown in your jsf, you need to prevent StreamContent from being null

Comment: how i can pass reload ? becouse this removing `taskid` from url

Comment: if the reload was triggered by an exception, you can't, if the reload was triggered by the download button you check this link on how to add parameters to a button: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4994833/2546444

Comment: As @DennisKriegel states, prevent the situation from happening. Make sure there is no and can't be an error.

Comment: @Kukeltje  im not understand, if method  `getFile` return `null` jsf\primefaces considers this exception ?

Comment: Yes, and validly so...it is a ***programming/design*** error. How can getFile() return null? If the file is not available? Then prevent the download button from being active ***that*** is how you solve things... ***upfront***

Comment: @Kukeltje return null when no permission to that file,not avalible etc.... And very strangely PF reload page on this error , while i`m handling on bean this and send message with error to UI;

Comment: No, not strange, you use `p:fileDownload` in a wrong way as @DennisKriechel pointed out in the answer. **Your** implementation is for the non-p:fileDownload download (plain jsf) way... Search stackoverflow for full solutions...

Comment: there are two way you can go, a dirty one and a fine one:
1. (dirty) Simply provide an empty DefaultStreamdContent (`new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[] {});`)
2. Create a two stage download process. First you use an ajax button which the user presses in order to determine if the file is available. The user then receive a second link (the pf download button) in order to load the content you have already prepared in your bean.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem where I don't want to refresh the page if the file to download is `null`. I solved the problem by disabling the button that let the user download the file by generating the file before the actual download and checking his existance:

```
<p:commandButton disabled="#{ReportBean.contentToDownload eq null}">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{ReportBean.downloadPdf()}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

I find this solution more elegant than letting user click twice. Users hates clicking twice.