# Why only the last <f:param> action is called?

Tags: jsf, commandlink

I have a list of commandLinks in a JSF page where each commandLink sets to the corresponding page in a content.xhtml page.

Problem: In the below list of `commandLink`s only the last one works successfully:

```
<ui:composition>
    <h:form>
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li>
            <h:commandLink value="Title1"  >
                <f:param  value="#{pageBean.setPage('title1')}" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h:commandLink value="Title2"   >
                <f:param value="#{pageBean.setPage('title2')}" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h:commandLink value="Title3"  >
                <f:param  value="#{pageBean.setPage('title3')}" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </li>           
     </ul>     
  </h:form>
```

Per [How can I pass selected row to commandLink inside dataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-selected-row-to-commandlink-inside-datatable) Item Number 2, I understand that there is a need of accessing the request parameter map. Is this correct in this case with `<f:param>`? How can I set one page to be included below with the correct title page?

content.xhtml

```
<ui:composition>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

            <div id="target" class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">                    
              <ui:insert name="content" >  
                <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/#{pageBean.page}.xhtml" /> 
              </ui:insert>          
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ui:composition>
```

PageBean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class PageBean implements Serializable {

    private String page;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        page = "title1"; //  Default include.
    }

//getter & setter
}
```

**Related to the problem**: when PageBean is RequestScoped events inside title1 work properly but the commandLinks fail. when PageBean is ViewScoped event in title1 don't work and I have only the last commandLink working.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

---

**EDIT** (per below mentioned tutorial):

```
        <li>
            <h:commandLink value="Title1" action="#{pageBean.setPage}" >
                <f:param  name="action" value="title1" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </li>
```

The below method is NOT called

```
public void setPage() {

    Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

    String page = params.get("action");

    System.out.println("page " + page);

    this.page = page;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong use of f:param and wrong way to call setPage method. http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar: I have used the mentioned tutorial but the setPage() method is not called.

Comment: while i will ignore the nomenclature of an action method's name please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked and debug

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar: Thanks. which Item do you think is causing the problem?