# sending selected row using f:attribute giving classcastexception

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Primefaces 5.3 JSF 2.1 glassfish 4.0

i know there are many ways of sending a selected row but i am using f:attribute i have used it many many times before but for some reason it is giving me a javax.servlet.ServletException: ng.requests.model.Request cannot be cast to java.lang.String

backing bean

```
@Named(value = "rtBean")
@ViewScoped
public class BeanRequests  implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Inject
    ManagerRequests rtm;
    private StreamedContent file;


    public List<Request> getRequests(){

        return rtm.findAll();

    }

    public void buttonAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {

        Request form=(Request) actionEvent.getComponent().getAttributes().get("form");      
        Requestattachment ra=form.getRequestattachment();

        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(ra.getAttachment());
        //System.out.println(ra.getRaid());
        file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream,"application/pdf",form.getTrackingno()+".pdf");

    } 

    public StreamedContent getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(StreamedContent file) {
        this.file = file;
    }



}
```

view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Request Form Records</title>
    <f:facet name="first">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    </f:facet>
</h:head>
<h:body styleClass="body">
    <h:form>
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"  life="2000"/>
        <p:dataTable value="#{rtBean.getRequests()}" var="rf"
        id="tb1" paginator="true" rows="50" style="font-size:70%"
        >

            <p:column headerText="Attachment" exportable="false">
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s" disabled="#{rf.attachmentAvailable()}" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(showStatus, hideStatus)" actionListener="#{rtBean.buttonAction}">
                       <f:attribute name="form" value="#{rf}"></f:attribute>

                        <p:fileDownload value="#{rtBean.file}"/>
                </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

model

```
    package ng.requests.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.util.Date;


/**
 * The persistent class for the request database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Request.findAll", query="SELECT r FROM Request r")
public class Request implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idrequest;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date date;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date expdate;

    private String requester;

    private String status;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="userid")
    private User user;

    //bi-directional one-to-one association to Requestattachment
    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="raid")
    private Requestattachment requestattachment;

    @Transient
    private String trackingno;

    public Request() {
    }

    public int getIdrequest() {
        return this.idrequest;
    }

    public void setIdrequest(int idrequest) {
        this.idrequest = idrequest;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Date getExpdate() {
        return this.expdate;
    }

    public void setExpdate(Date expdate) {
        this.expdate = expdate;
    }

    public String getRequester() {
        return this.requester;
    }

    public void setRequester(String requester) {
        this.requester = requester;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Requestattachment getRequestattachment() {
        return this.requestattachment;
    }

    public void setRequestattachment(Requestattachment requestattachment) {
        this.requestattachment = requestattachment;
    }

    public String getTrackingno() {
        trackingno="TCD-"+getIdrequest();
        return trackingno;
    }

    public void setTrackingno(String trackingno) {
        this.trackingno = trackingno;
    }



    public Boolean attachmentAvailable(){
        if(requestattachment==null){
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    }
```

exception

```
    2016-12-13T18:58:45.147+0300|Severe: Error Rendering View[/requests.xhtml]
java.lang.ClassCastException: ng.requests.model.Request cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButton.getForm(CommandButton.java:254)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.buildAjaxRequest(CoreRenderer.java:362)
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.buildRequest(CommandButtonRenderer.java:123)
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeMarkup(CommandButtonRenderer.java:65)
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(CommandButtonRenderer.java:54)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at org.primefaces.component.column.Column.renderChildren(Column.java:336)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeCell(DataTableRenderer.java:1022)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRow(DataTableRenderer.java:970)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRows(DataTableRenderer.java:878)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:825)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:788)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:281)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:243)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:85)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

2016-12-13T18:58:45.150+0300|Warning: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: ng.requests.model.Request cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButton.getForm(CommandButton.java:254)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.buildAjaxRequest(CoreRenderer.java:362)
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.buildRequest(CommandButtonRenderer.java:123)
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeMarkup(CommandButtonRenderer.java:65)
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(CommandButtonRenderer.java:54)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at org.primefaces.component.column.Column.renderChildren(Column.java:336)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeCell(DataTableRenderer.java:1022)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRow(DataTableRenderer.java:970)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRows(DataTableRenderer.java:878)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:825)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:788)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:281)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:243)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:85)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:443)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

based on suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-selected-row-to-commandlink-inside-datatable) i tried to use f:setPropertyActionListener but i keep getting nullpointerexception for form

```
<p:column headerText="Attachment" exportable="false">
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s" disabled="#{rf.attachmentAvailable()}" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(showStatus, hideStatus)" actionListener="#{rtBean.buttonAction}">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{rtBean.form}" value="#{rf}"/>

                        <p:fileDownload value="#{rtBean.file}"/>
                </p:commandButton>
</p:column>
```

backing bean

```
  package ng.requests.view;




@Named(value = "rtBean")
@ViewScoped
public class BeanRequests  implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Inject
    ManagerRequests rtm;
    private StreamedContent file;
    private Request form;

    public List<Request> getRequests(){

        return rtm.findAll();

    }

    public void buttonAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("here  "+form.getIdrequest());

        Requestattachment ra=form.getRequestattachment();

        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(ra.getAttachment());
        //System.out.println(ra.getRaid());
        file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream,"application/pdf",form.getTrackingno()+".pdf");






    } 

    public StreamedContent getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(StreamedContent file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public Request getForm() {
        return form;
    }

    public void setForm(Request form) {
        this.form = form;
    }

}
```

I would prefer to use f:attribute as i have used it in all my previous projects but i cant figure out why the cast exception

Comment: Try renaming 'form' to e.g. 'myform'. Might be the 'for,' is some kind of 'reserved' attribute.

Comment: @Kukeltje wow it worked thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'form' is an existing [attribute of the `p:commandButton`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/6.0/core/primefaces-p/commandButton.html)  (as kindly state by BalusC)  so passing it on via an`f:attribute`makes the component get something else (your object) than it expects (reference to a form). What effectively is done is

```
<p:commandButton form="#{rf}"... />
```

and consequently the ClasscastException is thrown. Changing the attribute name to some other name, e.g. 'myform' will make it work. So something like

```
<f:attribute name="myform" value="#{rf}"/>
```

and in the bean:

```
Request form=(Request) actionEvent.getComponent().getAttributes().get("myform");
```