# Current element in a h:dataTable

Tags: java, spring, jsf, datatable

So I have the following code:

```xhtml
<h:dataTable value="#{findRepairsBean.repairs}" var="r"
    styleClass="repair-table"
    headerClass="repair-table-header"
    rowClasses="repair-table-odd-row,repair-table-even-row">                       
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Product</f:facet>
        #{r.item.productName}
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Brand</f:facet>
        #{r.item.brand}
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Category</f:facet>
        #{r.item.category}
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
    <!-- column header -->
    <f:facet name="header">Defect</f:facet>
    <!-- row record -->
    #{r.details.defect}
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Description</f:facet>
    #{r.details.description}
    </h:column> 
    <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Status</f:facet>
    #{r.details.status}
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
         <h:outputLabel for="price" value="Price: "/>
         <h:inputText id="price" value="#{findRepairsBean.price}"/>
         <h:message for="price" styleClass="error" /> 
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
         <h:commandButton styleClass="mybutton" 
            value="Place Bid" action="#{findRepairsBean.placeBid(???)}"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

This is my bean:

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class FindRepairsBean implements Serializable{
    @Autowired
    private RepairService repairService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    private String keyWord;
    private int price;
    private List<Repair> repairs;
    //private Repair repair;

    @Inject
    private UserBean userBean;

    public void findRepairs(){
        repairs = repairService.findRepairsByKeyword(keyWord);
    }

    public void placeBid(Repair repair){
        try {
            Repairer repairer = (Repairer) userService.getUser(userBean.getUsername());
            repairService.placeBid(repairer, repair, price);
        } catch(UserServiceException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(TestRepairCafe.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(ex.getLocalizedMessage())); // Add global message
        }
    }

    public String getKeyWord() {
        return keyWord;
    }

    public void setKeyWord(String keyWord) {
        this.keyWord = keyWord;
    }

    public List<Repair> getRepairs() {
        return repairs;
    }

    public void setRepairs(List<Repair> repairs) {
        this.repairs = repairs;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

And this is the model of Repair:

```
public class Repair implements Comparable<Repair>, Serializable
{
    private static int repairCounter = 0;
    private final int repairId;
    private Client client;    
    private Repairer repairer;    
    private RepairDetails details;
    private Item item;        
    private final List<Bid> bids;        

    private Repair()
    {
        this.repairId = repairCounter++;
        this.bids = new ArrayList<>();                
    }

    public Repair(Item item, RepairDetails repDetails)
    {
        this();
        this.item = item;
        this.details = repDetails;
    }

    public void addBid(Bid bid)
    {
        this.bids.add(bid);
    }

    public void addClient(Client client)
    {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public void setRepairer(Repairer repairer)
    {
        this.repairer = repairer;
    }

    public int getRepairId()
    {
        return repairId;
    }

    public List<Bid> getBids()
    {
        return bids;
    }

    public RepairDetails getDetails()
    {
        return details;
    }

    public Client getClient()
    {
        return client;
    }

    public Repairer getRepairer()
    {
        return repairer;
    }

    public Item getItem()
    {
        return item;
    }

    public void setDetails(RepairDetails details)
    {
        this.details = details;
    }

    public void setItem(Item item)
    {
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Repair o)
    {
        return this.details.getSubmitDate().compareTo(o.getDetails().getSubmitDate());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%s -%s", this.getDetails().getDescription(), item.getProductName());
    }

}
```

Now, in this xhtml page I am making a datatable of all repairs which contain a keyword, which is working perfectly. However the placeBid() method in my bean is supposed to place a bid on a Repair, only I do not know how to give the current Repair in the table to the placeBid() method. I would expect I could just do it with #{r}, however this is not compiling. I want to store each repair in the list somehow so I can acces it in my method for each row in the table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I pass a parameter to a commandLink inside a datatable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994458/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-commandlink-inside-a-datatable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try with this syntax?

```
<h:commandButton styleClass="mybutton"  
   value="Place Bid" action="#{findRepairsBean.placeBid(r)}"/>
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927157/getting-selected-row-data-from-datatable-in-jsf) this should work if using the correct EL version (2.2), see [here](http://balusc.blogspot.be/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html#ReallySimpleCRUDNowWithoutDataModel) another example.